# Apple Watch Table on row selected crash

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, watchkit

I am using Xamarin to develop an Apple Watch app. I added a table (WKInterfaceTable) and populate it with code-behind. But when I click on a row, the app immediately crashes.

To get this far, I actually manually edited the storyboard XML file, because it wouldn't work by simply dragging and dropping a table on the storyboard. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.WatchKit.Storyboard" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6221" systemVersion="14A389" targetRuntime="watchKit" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="AgC-eL-Hgc">
<dependencies>
<plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6213"/>
<plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBWatchKitPlugin" version="3734"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--Interface Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="aou-V4-d1y">
        <objects>
            <controller id="AgC-eL-Hgc" title="Favorites" customClass="InterfaceController" customModuleProvider="">
                <items>
                    <table alignment="left" id="nXC-Mh-TYy">
                        <items>
                            <tableRow identifier="default" id="zJA-dk-zIT" customClass="FavoriteRowController">
                                <group key="rootItem" width="1" height="40" alignment="left" spacing="6" id="ASs-9x-fCK">
                                    <items>
                                        <imageView width="35" height="35" alignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" image="Door" id="rac-gq-1kM"/>
                                        <label alignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" text="Location" id="jkO-KQ-vGr"/>
                                    </items>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.93625843524932861" green="0.94465947151184082" blue="0.98500943183898926" alpha="0.14000000000000001" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <edgeInsets key="margins" left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2"/>
                                </group>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="RowLabel" destination="jkO-KQ-vGr" id="Hcb-P2-F5Q"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableRow>
                        </items>
                    </table>
                </items>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="InterfaceTable" destination="nXC-Mh-TYy" id="4YS-uT-eWw"/>
                </connections>
            </controller>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
```

Did I get something wrong in the XML?

Code for `InterfaceController`:

```
public partial class InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
{
    protected InterfaceController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void Awake(NSObject context)
    {
        base.Awake(context);

        this.LoadTableData();

        // Configure interface objects here.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} awake with context", this);
    }

    public override void WillActivate()
    {
        // This method is called when the watch view controller is about to be visible to the user.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} will activate", this);
    }

    public override void DidDeactivate()
    {
        // This method is called when the watch view controller is no longer visible to the user.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} did deactivate", this);
    }

    private void LoadTableData()
    {
        var cityNames = new[] { "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5" };

        InterfaceTable.SetNumberOfRows(cityNames.Length, "default");

        for (var i = 0; i < cityNames.Length; i++)
        {
            var row = (FavoriteRowController)InterfaceTable.GetRowController(i);
            row.RowLabel.SetText(cityNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `InterfaceController.designer.cs`:

```
[Register("InterfaceController")]
partial class InterfaceController
{
    [Outlet]
    public WKInterfaceTable InterfaceTable { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets()
    {
        if (InterfaceTable != null)
        {
            InterfaceTable.Dispose();
            InterfaceTable = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `FavoriteRowController`:

```
public partial class FavoriteRowController : WKInterfaceController
{
    protected FavoriteRowController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void Awake(NSObject context)
    {
        base.Awake(context);

        // Configure interface objects here.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} awake with context", this);
    }

    public override void WillActivate()
    {
        // This method is called when the watch view controller is about to be visible to the user.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} will activate", this);
    }

    public override void DidDeactivate()
    {
        // This method is called when the watch view controller is no longer visible to the user.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} did deactivate", this);
    }
}
```

Code for `FavoriteRowController.designer.cs`:

```
[Register("FavoriteRowController")]
partial class FavoriteRowController
{
    [Outlet]
    public WKInterfaceLabel RowLabel { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets()
    {
    }
}
```

The exception of the crash in the application output:

`2016-11-03 10:10:58.780 MyAppWatchExtension[16255:474000] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FavoriteRowController 0x799ec7e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key InterfaceTable.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00383a22 __exceptionPreprocess + 194
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x059a0e76 objc_exception_throw + 52
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00383951 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x013c5732 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 238
    4   Foundation                          0x012eac53 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 146
    5   Foundation                          0x012eab3b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 282
    6   WatchKit                            0x04b06c16 __58-[SPRemoteInterface handlePlistDictionary:fromIdentifier:]_block_invoke.882 + 39
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x06252c4f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0627550f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0625be31 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1031
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00343e7e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00306dcf __CFRunLoopRun + 2319
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0030624b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 395
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x003060ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    14  Foundation                          0x012c5192 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
    15  Foundation                          0x012c504f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 69
    16  libxpc.dylib                        0x0656d8a5 _xpc_objc_main + 476
    17  libxpc.dylib                        0x06570175 xpc_main + 215
    18  Foundation                          0x01323880 +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
    19  PlugInKit                           0x111556b6 -[PKService run] + 954
    20  WatchKit                            0x04b43108 main + 148
    21  libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x0584fb33 xamarin_main + 3475
    22  TycoMobilePassUIiOSWatchExtension   0x001055bc xamarin_watchextension_main + 124
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x062ae85d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: If it loads the table then it is probably not the storyboard. Could you add your code too that you use when the table row is selected? Are you using xamarin studio or VS?

Comment: Also I would not edit the storyboard file manually unless it is a small change (a simple value). It is not like Android the Ids are generated and it can be messed up easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crash happens when selecting an item and not when displaying the Table then I would assume it is to do with the row selection code, and would start there.

There are two options here depending on what you are trying todo:

**DidSelectRow**

Used when the row is selected and you want to manipulate some data or move to another view.

```
public override async void DidSelectRow(WKInterfaceTable table, nint rowIndex)
{
    var contextForNextInterfaceController = rows[(int)rowIndex]; // this depends how you have set up the table.
    Console.WriteLine($"Row selected: {rowData}");
    PushController("TheNextInterFaceController", contextForNextInterfaceController);
}
```

**GetContextForSegue**

Used when you set a segue in iOS Designer or Xcode so you can set the context for the next interface controller you are using.

```
public override NSObject GetContextForSegue(string segueIdentifier, WKInterfaceTable table, nint rowIndex)
{
    // Can check segueIdentifier if using more segues
    return new ContextForNextInterfaceController() // This needs to sub class NSObject
    {
        model = modelForNextInterfaceController,
    };
}
```

When moving to another view after setting the context you will neext to cast the context object and check it is of the type you are looking for:

```
public override void Awake(NSObject context)
{
    base.Awake(context);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} awake with context", this);
    var currentContext = context as ContextForNextInterfaceController;
    if (currentContext != null)
    {
        // Do stuff with context
    }
}
```

If you could post your Interface Controller code or the row selection code, then I might be able to help more. Also if you are getting any error in the application output that could be helpful too.

===========================================================================
**Update**

Ok from your error output I would says its the `FavoriteRowController` thats missing an outlet or wrong class set in the storyboard.

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key InterfaceTable.'

Is a common error when you are missing a outlet or removed one but not removed the link in the storyboard.

RowControllers dont need to be InterfaceControllers so I would set it up like so:

Code for `FavoriteRowController`:

```
using Foundation;

namespace WatchConnectivity.OnWatchExtension
{
    public partial class FavoriteRowController : NSObject
    {
        protected FavoriteRowController()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `FavoriteRowController.designer.cs`:

```
using Foundation;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace WatchConnectivity.OnWatchExtension
{
    [Register ("FavoriteRowController")]
    partial class FavoriteRowController
    {
        [Outlet]
        public WatchKit.WKInterfaceLabel RowLabel { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (RowLabel != null) {
                RowLabel.Dispose ();
                RowLabel = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [sample](https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/WatchTable)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, it was because my RowController class is supposed to derive from `NSObject`, not `WKInterfaceController`